# Fast algorithm or library to union many convex polygons

Tags: polygon, computational-geometry

I need to apply boolean OR operation (a.k.a union) on many convex polygons (up to tens of thousands), every polygon has fewer than 100 vertices. I tried Boost.Geometry (boost::geometry::union_() function), it needs about 200ms to union 1500 polygons.

I have already implemented a simple optimization:

1. separate the polygons into two groups,
2. recursively union the two groups into two polygon sets,
3. union the final two polygon sets.

This optimization is about 10 times faster than union the polygons one by one.

I need an algorithm or a C/C++ library to complete such operations in about 10ms.

Any suggestions ?

==== EDIT ====

I have replaced Boost.Geometry with Clipper (http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php), and it satisfies my requirements. Clipper can union multiple polygons in one operation (Boost.Geometry can only union two at a time), which probably is the reason it's much faster than Boost.Geometry.

Comment: Have you already parallelized the algorithm?

Comment: @NicoSchertler tried to parallelize the algorithm, improvements are negligible

Comment: Are you sure? How did you implement it?

Comment: 20 ms for 1500 polygons is a very decent performance !

Comment: @user416983, You can move the edit into an answer. You are allowed to answer your own questions.  Seems like this kind of situation (where you figured out the answer yourself) is a perfect example of why you are allowed.

Comment: Did you tried boost geometry multipolygon for union ?

Comment: @eykanal, moving this from answer to comment per request.  The time to compute would depend quite a bit on how many vertices the polygons have. Even a circle, or any "smooth" convex shape, on a digital screen can be represented as some polygon.  As a side note, a hull of a union of two convex polygons will almost never have a convex boundary.  Not sure if the comment is still relevant since the author of the question managed to answer it on his own.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a scanline algorithm that will process all polygons in a single go.

Orient all edges top-down and sort them top-down by the ordinate of the top vertex.

Maintain an active list, i.e. a list of all edges that cross the horizontal through the current vertex. For a position of the line, you can determine all intersections with the active edges. Keep the active edges sorted horizontally, by the abscissa of the intersection.

When you move from one vertex to the next, some edges enter the list and others leave it. Also, during sorting some edges can get swapped, which indicates that they intersect.

The intersections go in pairs, tracing line segments inside the polygons. Merging all segments along the horizontal is a simple 1D problem.

Putting all these ingredients together, by linking the output of the merge from one position of the scanline to the next, you will form a graph that corresponds to the final union. It is not necessarily connected.

It should be possible to implement the whole process as a single pass, and avoid fragmenting the edges where not needed.

And with some care on how the active list processing is organized, the algorithm should run in time O(N Log(N) + NK), where K is the number of side intersections.